# Bitcoin Conf file missing windows 8

Tags: bitcoin-core

I am trying to set up the bitcoin rpc login but I cant seem to find the bitcoin.conf file on the windows 8 file system ive looked under myusername/roaming/bitcoin no file there or anywhere else I have looked anyone else have any idea? thanks!! ill continue looking thanks ahead of time :)

Comment: You have to create the file if it is missing.

Comment: Should be `users\username\AppData\Roaming\Bitcoin\ ` is that what you meant? (Application Data folder was renamed appdata for win8)

Comment: figured out I gotta create it and ya I went to that location im opening up bitcoind.exe now and getting an error with my config file :/ gonna read the bitcoin documentation again..

Comment: Exception: N5boost16exception_detail10clone_19error_info_injectorINS_15
program_options26invalid_config_file_syntaxEEEEE
the options configuration contains an invalid line ‘ ’
C:\Program Files <x86>\Bitcoin\daemon\bitcoind.exe in AppInit<>

Comment: You're going to need to post your configuration file to get help with that. Be sure to remove passwords and other sensitive data first!